# Why does my FileStream.Read only output zeros and doesn't read the file

Tags: c#, filestream, logic-error

The code below is only outputting zeros when the first byte should give at least `93` and `32` based on the file it writes, but it doesn't even give the number of bytes it reads from the file it makes/edits and the bytes are shown

[image: Stream]

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) LZMA[i] = database[i + place];
//uses bytes from another file to get LZMA code

FileStream LZMAFILE = File.Create("LZMAStream.lzma");
//Creates file

LZMAFILE.Write(LZMA);
//writes bytes to file (linked above)

//now I check to see if it can read my file
byte[] properties = new byte[5];
//makes properties array

int bruh = LZMAFILE.Read(properties, 0, 5);
//reads array and gives number of bytes

//returns 0 for everything therefore the dll down there doesn't work

LZMACoder.Decompress(LZMAFILE);
```

Comment: Try to Flush (`LZMAFILE.Flush()`) your stream and set the Position to 0 before re-reading it.

Comment: dude I've been trying to figure something out with the position but I thought that only had to do with the search function like dude holy crap I'm so happy now, you might understand but now that my program actually works I can finally move forward

Comment: You should also use "using" to ensure disposable objects, like files, are disposed.

Comment: thanks, I would usually use a dispose function because sometimes I can use gigabytes of memory for just looking through images in a file

Comment: You shouldn't use `Dispose` yourself, instead put it in a `using` block